# when an element clicked another element(object) sends to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume we have these two elements:

```
<div id="item1Id" onclick="myFunction()">item1</div>
<div id="item2Id">item2</div>
```

I want to get object of 'item2' instead of 'item1' in "myFunction()", something like this:

```
function myFunction()
{
     changeObjects('item2Id'); // clearly this is what I want
     console.log(this.innerHTML);
}

output:item2
```

**Note!** I know this work can do bye something like **document.getElementById** or **document.getElementsByClassName**, but I exactly want to get current object.
excuse me for my poor english language.
thanks alot.

Comment: Well, there's no way to get the element wihtout using one of the DOM methods, like `getElementById`, so how exactly do you want to get the element ?

Comment: place both divs in a div then you can get the current object using `$(this).siblings('#item2Id')`

Comment: if you want to et a DOM elemet, you will need to use DOM methods. for instance document.getElementById

Comment: @Shah Rukh doesnt work your offer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("div[id*='item']").next();` or `$("div[id*='item']").prev();`

Or iterate through `$("div[id*='item']")` using `.eq()`

`$("div[id*='item']")` selects the elements that have an id attribute containing the word `item` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing of this sort might help :-

```
<div id="item1Id1" onclick="myFunction(this)">item1</div>
<div id="item1Id2" >item2</div>



 <script>  
        function myFunction(obj)
     {
           console.log($(obj).next());
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: As you asked that you wanted to get current object ... and what property(id/className) do you know about the div to be find ??

Comment: you use next function, I say maybe a div be in header and the other be in footer!!!!
now you think your code is useful?!

Comment: You did not understand what I'm saying dear @Alok,
please see question again, I send Id of target element to " changeObjects" function, yoo see!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/haridharan/Yt2GG/) ,Try this,

```
   $("#item1Id").click(function(){
      alert($(this).next().text());
    });
```

Comment: then use id of object,`function myFunction()
{
     changeObjects($("#item2Id")); // clearly this is what I want
     console.log(this.innerHTML);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Add JQuery lib to use above method

```
function myFunction()
{
    alert( $('#item2Id').text() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction()
{
    (function(){
        console.log(this.innerHTML);
    }).call(document.getElementById('item2Id'));
}
```